# reading more than one word from user

Tags: java

### main class :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Student std = new Student();

        System.out.println("plz , inter id :");
        std.setId(input.nextInt());

        System.out.println("plz , inter name :");
        std.setName(input.next());

        System.out.println("plz , inter Age :");
        std.setAge(input.nextInt());

        System.out.println("plz , inter department :");
        std.setDepartment(input.next());

        System.out.println("plz , inter GPA :");
        std.setGpa(input.nextFloat());

        std.printStudentInfo();

    }
}
```

### Student class :

```
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String department;
    private float gpa;

    public void setId(int Pid) {
        this.id = Pid;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setName(String Pname) {
        this.name = Pname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setAge(int Page) {
        this.age = Page;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String Pdepartment) {
        this.department = Pdepartment;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return this.department;
    }

    public void setGpa(float Pgpa) {
        this.gpa = Pgpa;
    }

    public float getGpa() {
        return this.gpa;
    }

    public void printStudentInfo() {
        System.out.println("--------------  " + "[" + this.id + "]" + "  "
                + this.name.toUpperCase() + " -----------------");
        System.out.println("age : " + this.age);
        System.out.println("Department : " + this.department);
        System.out.println("Gpa : " + this.gpa);
    }
}
```

this is a simple application that reads some data from  the user and print it out , I want to read more than one word from the user in my tow string fields "name , department" , but , when I inter department name of two or more words like   "computer science " , I get an error , I also tried to use `nextline()` instead of `next()` , similar results , I end up making another error !

Comment: nextLine() should work but it returns always Strings - perhaps you tried to save a string in some other variable?

Comment: using next() , i get : java.util.InputMismatchException !

Comment: it works fine with a string that contain no spaces ! But when i try to use a multiple word string , it throw me an exception , no matter what method of next I'm using !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, just add this :

```
    input.useDelimiter("\r\n");
```

after

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

No need to `readLine()`.

From javadoc :

```
public Scanner useDelimiter(Pattern pattern)

Sets this scanner's delimiting pattern to the specified pattern.

Parameters:
    pattern - A delimiting pattern
Returns:
    this scanner
```

It means that the pattern set will be the delimiter when you will call `next[...]()`. It will split according to this pattern. 
So the default one is obviously a space. In fact this is : `\p{javaWhitespace}+`

Comment: it works like a charm ^^ , but can you put an extra effort and explain what just happened ?! ,

Comment: @Moawia307 thisn mean that the `return` or new line character will not count in your `input.next()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `input.nextInt()` only reads an integer. So when you press enter after your number, the `input.next()` will scan that newline instead of the input you type. So try to add an extra `input.nextLine()` to filter that newline and scan for your correct input:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

Student std = new Student();

System.out.println("plz , inter id :");
std.setId(input.nextInt()); //scans the number until newline

input.nextLine(); //scans the newline from the previous input
System.out.println("plz , inter name :");
std.setName(input.nextLine());

System.out.println("plz , inter Age :");
std.setAge(input.nextInt());

input.nextLine();   
System.out.println("plz , inter department :");
std.setDepartment(input.nextLine());

System.out.println("plz , inter GPA :");
std.setGpa(input.nextFloat());

std.printStudentInfo();
```

Note: this code is **[tested](https://ideone.com/OnOLnQ)**